# What's another way of saying that something 'captures the essence' of something?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I'm having a hard time coming up with a similar phrase or word, and have already used 'captures the essence' nearby.

In context:

> Unfortunately, this quantity is impossible to calculate in practice, as *P* is a continuous random variable, and we only have finitely many samples in a real dataset. Therefore, it is necessary to use a proxy metric that **captures the essence** of (2.36).

Comment: Why not just say, "use a proxy for X"?  But if you must qualify the proxy, then you want one that "correlates well with X"

Comment: Context is very important. Is your example the only context?

Comment: ... to use as a proxy a metric that "behaves like" ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***represents*** to replace **captures the essence *of*** (yes, including the trailing *of*).

> Therefore, it is necessary to use a proxy metric that ***represents***
>   [captures the essence of] ...

ODO:

> **[represent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/represent)**
>   *VERB*
>
> 3.2 (of a sign or symbol) have a particular signification; stand for.

Answer (score -1):

A word that would work is "**emulate**".

> Therefore, it is necessary to use a proxy metric that **emulates** the
>   real series of calculations.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/emulated

Answer (score -1):

"Therefore, it is necessary to use a proxy metric that **comes close to** (2.36)"
"Therefore, it is necessary to use a proxy metric that **is on par with** (2.36)"
"Therefore, it is necessary to use a proxy metric that **sums up** (2.36)"